# TypeError: conv1d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input' on Tf 1.13.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using `Tensorflow 1.13.1` for a project.

It contains

```
batch_x = tf.nn.conv1d(input=batch_x, filters=eye_filter, stride=1, padding='SAME')
```

According to `https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d` the `input` keyword exists.

Yet I get

`TypeError: conv1d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input'`

Comment: The documentation you cite is for version 1.15 but your question title says you are using version 1.13.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TF 1.13`, then allowable arguments are as shown below

```
tf.nn.conv1d(value,
           filters,
           stride,
           padding,
           use_cudnn_on_gpu=None,
           data_format=None,
           name=None)
```

To work in `TF 1.13`, then you can modify code as shown below

```
batch_x = tf.nn.conv1d(value=batch_x, filters=eye_filter, stride=1, padding='SAME')
```

In `TF 1.15`, allowable arguments are as shown below, where `input is alias for value`.

```
tf.nn.conv1d(
    value=None, filters=None, stride=None, padding=None, use_cudnn_on_gpu=None,
    data_format=None, name=None, input=None, dilations=None
)
```

In  `TF 2.4`,allowable arguments are as shown below

```
tf.nn.conv1d(
    input, filters, stride, padding, data_format='NWC', dilations=None,
    name=None
)
```

For more information you can refer [TF 1.13](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3412-L3483) source code.